# How to enable debugging in the nginx?

Tags: nginx

I've added nginx offical repo as per http://wiki.nginx.org/Install . Installed `nginx-debug` package (for CentOS 6.5 x86_64), which clearly says:

```
Description : Not stripped version of nginx built with the debugging log
        : support.
```

But still, `--with-debug` flag is missing from `nginx -V` output and of course no debug logs.

Could not find any info on how would I enable debugging from RPMs, all info is based on compile time configuration.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. `repoquery -l nginx-debug` showed that it installed only 1 file `/usr/sbin/nginx-debug`. Now I could simply edit `/etc/sysconfig/nginx` file, and change nginx executable from `/usr/sbin/nginx` to `/usr/sbin/nginx-debug`. And it works. I see my debug logs.